# How to insert 2 functions into onClick event ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick, event-handling

```
<Button onClick={submitHandler}>
```

I have this button which already has an assigned function to its onClick event. I also want to add `<Button onClick={() => Toggle()}>`  this Toggle function into same button. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a function which calls both of the functions. Assuming `submitHandler` needs the event object, that will look like:

```
<Button onClick={(event) => {
  submitHandler(event);
  Toggle();
})}>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle event you need to do onClick={(e) => { submitHandler(e); Toggle(); }.

if you don't want to handle event just do onClick={() => { submitHandler(); Toggle(); }.

Answer (score 0):

First, think of separating your functions you can do something like :

```
<Button onClick={(e) => handleClick}>
```

And then create your functions which gonna look like:

```
const handleClick = (e) => { handleSubmit(e); handleToggle();}
```

You can later work on each function apart:

```
const handleSubmit() => { // your code  }
const handleToggle() => { // your code  }
```